# Oracle sql ORA-02291 parent key not found

Tags: sql, oracle, parent

I have a copied table:

```
CREATE TABLE d_clients_copy As SELECT * FROM d_clients;
```

Only data structure and values are copied, constraints not.

So I am adding the Primary Key to the newly created data base:

```
ALTER TABLE d_clients_copy
add CONSTRAINT client_number_pk
    PRIMARY KEY (client_number);
```

Now I have a primary key column in the newly created table.

I have a table with events, and I'm trying to reference the client_number from the c_clients_copy table.

```
ALTER TABLE d_events_copy
add CONSTRAINT client_number_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (client_number)
    REFERENCES d_clients_copy (client_number);
```

And oracle gives the following error:

> ORA-02298: cannot validate ... - parent keys not found.

Which one is the parent? I am so confused.

Note: each table contains data.

Comment: The `client_number` column in `d_events_copy` table contains those values not present in `client_number` column of `d_clients_copy` table. That's why this error.

Comment: @Noel Table  `d_events_copy` was created using `SELECT * FROM d_clients` without `where` clause, so I think there are the same data.

Comment: I don't know what data is there in the tables. But, the error is definitely due to child table having the data not present in parent table. Let the OP check the data. `select client_number from d_events_copy where client_number not in (select client_number from d_clients_copy)`

Comment: The error was caused because in the d_events_copy I have values that are not present in the d_clients_copy table.

Answer (score 2):

When you copied the two tables you possibly had changes occurring between the time that the selects were issued.

By default the second select will not be selecting data as of the same time as the first select because the default query isolation level for Oracle is READ COMMITTED.

To change this behaviour you have to modify the query isolation level for the session to SERIALIZABLE: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/consist.htm#CNCPT1320